# Adding Linker Flags will lead to fail the build

Tags: xamarin.ios, linker-flags

I'm using two third party frameworks, one Swift and one Objective C inside my Xamarin iOS project. I was asked to add following Linker Flags for those frameworks.

```
-lz -lc++ -lstdc++ -ObjC
```

Once I add those flags, I'm getting build error

> MTOUCH: Error MT5216: Native linking failed

My questions are,

1. What are the meanings of those Linker Flags ?
2. Is there a place that I can find the Linker Flags with their descriptions?
3. How can I know which Linker flags would need for a third party framework?

Comment: I just know that, `-ObjC`: After adding this parameter, the linker will load all the target C classes and categories in the static library into the final executable file.And `-lz -lc++ -lstdc++` they are framwork used in project. Usually in Xcode be used to add missing framework.

Comment: I'm trying to use a Swift framework and an Objective C framework inside the Binding project in Xamarin iOS. I have no idea how those third party frameworks build. Is there any way that I can extract those details from `lipo` or `otool` commands?

Comment: Although I have no idea about using commands to to these however I know using Xcode can build Objective-C or Swift Framework . Here are two articles about OC and Swift binding to Xamarin.IOS can be refer .https://mobileprogrammerblog.wordpress.com/2017/09/17/objective-c-library-binding-for-xamarin-ios/ -- https://medium.com/@Flash3001/binding-swift-libraries-xamarin-ios-ff32adbc7c76